# Clicking when I brake..?

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, monte-carlo

I've been having an issue where when I brake I notice a clicking noise. Seems to happen at any speed.. Last night on my way home from work at around 11pm I noticed that when it clicks both my AC and headlights seem to react to the clicking. My AC blower kind of pulses as it clicks and my headlights dim with each click. Could this be a simple improperly installed brake like I've seen in similar questions or could it be electrical?

Car is a '99 Chevy Monte Carlo with the 3.1L V6

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question? This sounds like the anti-lock brakes are possibly not working correctly.

Comment: Sorry.. It's a '99 Chevy Monte Carlo with a 3.1L v6

Comment: Any feedback in the brake pedal when this happens?

Comment: None, can only feel it in the steering wheel.. No pulling or anything, just the vibration of the click.